# What is the best preposition for "touch down"?

Tags: prepositions

What is the best preposition for "touch down"? Can we use it without any preposition?

For example:

- We've just touched down Qatar.
- We've just touched down **at** Qatar.
- We've just touched down **in** Qatar.

OR

- We've just touched down **at** the airport.
- We've just touched down **in** the airport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "airport" refers to the entire aerodrome, including the runways and related buildings. However, when you say "**in**" an airport, that tends to refer to the buildings, because the runways etc are outside. So, saying a plane landed "in" an airport is incorrect, it should be "*we've just touched down **at** the airport*".

When it comes to the name of a town, city or country, we say that we are "in" it, so it would be correct to say "*we've just touched down **in** Qatar*".

The only context where "in" and "at" becomes a choice is if you are distinguishing between being within the boundaries, or at the perimeter of something. For example, you might arrive *at* a building by car, and then go *in* on foot.

Comment: "In" and "at" can become a problem with cities, towns, and smaller locations such as villages, at least in British usage. We say **in** London, Birmingham, Liverpool, etc, but we could say **at"* a small village, as we would for a landmark such as a road junction, lake, bridge, etc. It is interesting to see how "at" was used for some places in the past (e.g. Bristol) but now they are bigger, we see "in" instead.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't think that's true, Michael. I live **in** a village. I think you're thinking about directions, where we might say "to avoid London, turn around *at* Watford".

Comment: "After his return to England Govett lived at Tiverton, where he wrote several articles on New South Wales which were published in The Saturday Magazine"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good for him, but I definitely live **in** a village! I think when you're speaking about a place that is a locale of an area you are already in or speaking about, then it can be "at". From my perspective in Lancashire, I would say that someone lived "in Tiverton, Devon". But someone who lived in nearby Taunton, in Devon, may well say someone else lived "at Tiverton" like one might say "at the end of the road" or "at the other side of town".

Comment: I think the "at" usage for villages, hamlets, etc, is a little old-fashioned, but then so am I.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It would seriously depend on the size of the place. In some rural areas, there are place names that literally cover a single dwelling, or maybe a couple of dwellings at a road junction. You could only ever be "at" such a place, because the second you reach it, you're there. There is no centre. But we've gone way off topic for the question "What is the best preposition for “touch down”?